# design pattern to use for changing object properties from property inspector

Tags: oop, design-patterns, actionscript

I have this problem at hand and wanted some inputs on best way to approach it -

In my application, i have different set of objects and each object has some properties associated with them.

For eg: objects like, say, shapes ,  which has some common properties like color and specific properties ( for eg:  circle has radius and center has its specific property )

The user can change object properties through a property inspector.
Currently, the PI holds a object ID and uses that to talk to DOM for anything related to object it currently refers. like say, if it wants to change the property of object it will call DOM Api

`ChangeObjectProperty(objectID , *);`

(I hope using object ID to refer to objects inside the DOM is right way. (is there a better way to do this ?))

What should i pass as the second argument ? 
Should it be a single opaque object ( say, `IObjProps`) where each objects provides its own structure ?

For example the circle will have following structure of its own -

```
class CircleProps extends CommonProps
{
   public var radius:Number;
   public var center:Point;
}

class CommonProps extends IObjProps
{
   public function clone();
   public var color:Number;
}
```

The DOM will pass on this structure to the object and object takes care of applying the change.

So `ChangeObjectProperty(objectID , *);` function will be implemented as -

```
function ChangeObjectProperty(objectID , props:IObjProps)
{
  var object:Object = GetObjectFromID(objectID);
  object.SetProperty(iObjProps)
}
```

The problem with the above approach is that - its kind of difficult to know what specific property changed since its a single structure -

The alternative is to have property dictionary - the client inserts only the properties which got changed into the dictionary.

I wanted to know what is design pattern followed for such use cases.

Adding more info - this is actionscript -

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Could you continue your fruit analogy with some pseudo-code, please?

Comment: i revisited some of my previous questions and accepted the answers - thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: i edited the question and added some missing info. hope i made it better.

Comment: as mentioned in the question - this is ActionScript( OOP )